# NSURLSessionDownloadTask initiation in backgroundURLSession completionHandler

Tags: ios

I have a situation where I need to download multiple files sequentially as each download depends on its previous downloaded file. (I am processing the file in background itself)

I am using NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration.

There is a scenario where NSURLSessionDownloadTask initiates while the application is in background. This crashes the app with Assertion permittedbackgroundduration.

So, my question is, am I doing wrong by initiating the download task in background???

Thanks in advance,
- Satya

Comment: Are you capturing the `completionHandler` in `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` in the app delegate? And, in `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession` in your `NSURLSessionDelegate`, after initiating the other background request(s), did you call the saved `completionHandler`?

Comment: I'm not sure abt this... I am sending the same message for all download objects, so I feel that this is automatically done...

Comment: please see my comment for Leonardo's reply for the above thing

Comment: You show us your code for saving the completion handler, great, but where do you call that completion handler? Your error suggests that you're not calling the completion handler quickly enough, which means either that you're taking too much time before doing it (I think you have something like 30 sec, so I find that surprising) or you're somehow neglecting to call it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have limited time when on background, so chances are that you're taking too long to process the file.
If you don't call the completion handler fast enough, the system will crash your app.

Or you may have made a mistake and you are not calling the completion handler at all on the scenario where NSURLSessionDownloadTask initiates in background.

Comment: This is the code snippet used for saving the completion handler `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{
    self.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler = completionHandler;}
`

Comment: I am trying to read the file and save them into local data base in background... can that be a problem?

Comment: It could be. You can try recording the time it's taking to read and save the files in the DB. As Rob mentioned, I believe the time you have to process in background is around 30 sec.

Comment: very well said... the time to process the file in background is taking too much time... any way thanks guys for this discussion...